# Is it possible to get the embed tag attributes through jquery?

Tags: jquery

I tried

```
$('#w001').attr('width'); // return undefined
```

for tag:

```
<embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" class="w001" pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org" 
version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2"  
autoplay="yes" 
id="w001"  
width="512" 
height="384" 
rtsp-caching="80" 
</embed>
```

Comment: Your embed tag is closed incorrectly. You should close it with `/>` instead of `</embed>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get DOM using class selector.

```
$('embed.w001').attr('width');
```

Comment: Why should that help?

Answer (score 0):

it will work. [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xUbw9/)
use like this

```
$('#w001').attr('width');
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/nmV9X/

```
console.log($('#w001'))
console.log($('#w001').attr('width'))
```

Output:

```
jQuery(embed#w001.w001)
512
```